# How to send data to backend when dropdown selected in zapier

Tags: combobox, dropdown, zapier

Hello I have been trying to implement my app to zapier. I am able to authenticat through oauth2 and calls are going well but I am not able to pass data to back end when I use combobox.

I created two trigger
1) First trigger doesn't have trigger field, just a polling URL which fetch data from server and set variable. It works as expected. It sets data to lets say variable "X"

2) Second trigger is basicly for using "X" I have one trigger field "Y" which is combobox and as documentation I just write X.id.name and I can see combobox with field. I want to implement combobox selected event. I implement polling url like this http://mywebpage.com/myapi/{{Y}} . But whenever I test my zap , lets say I choose id = 5. it always request http://mywebpage.com/myapi/{{Y}} but not http://mywebpage.com/myapi/5 how can I solve it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the fix. I needed to change second trigger type to Unicode, because this way I can get selected one. Now is working.